# How complex is too complex for a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

List comprehensions are a very powerful tool in Python, but sometimes I find myself putting an awful lot of stuff inside of them. At what point is it better to write a function instead of putting it inside of a list comprehension?

For example:

```
>>> m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [''.join([[str(x) for x in i] for i in m][j]) for j in [0, 1, 2]]
['123', '456', '789']
```

Comment: When it becomes obtuse, unreadable, ....

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be rewritten to be more readable and concise:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print([''.join(map(str, sub)) for sub in m])

['123', '456', '789']
```

Generally I would stay away from code that you have posted. It is not the most readable code but that is an opinion which is basically the only answers you are likely to get bar asking Guido.

The zen of python should be a pointer to whether or not your  code is a good example of pythonic code.

```
In [49]: import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style and personal preference. When your list comprehension becomes unwieldy, it is better to convert it into a function. Good Python style emphasises code readability.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a hard and fast guideline - you'll have to evaluate the code on a case-by-case basis.  The most important thing to remember is that code is read more often than it is written - as such, even if something is more efficient (or more compact) it isn't necessarily better.  In your particular case it is rather hard to read an understand, and I'd recommend rewriting it (as suggested by Padraic) or putting it into a function.  Additionally you can use whitespace to more effectively organize your code.  Finally, if you're set on making it a list comprehension you could write helper function that you could call inside of your list comprehension - this would achieve a similar (but worse - use the standard library when possible) result as Padraic's solution.